# From pgfplotstable to standard table

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I like to use `pgfplotstable` to typeset my `csv` tables. However, I have to submit a paper using the basic standard `table` environment.

Is there a way to export a table generated by `pgfplotstable` to a `.tex` that doesn't require the `pgfplotstable` package?

If not, I'll probably export my table as a `.pdf` using the `standalone` class but I'd prefer a cleaner approach.

Comment: Could you better explain the problem? I think that `pgfplotstable` typesetting can produce a basic standard table, the main difference is that it uses an external file. If the problem is the external file, you can include it in your document inside a `filecontents` environment which creates the external file from your main tex file. An example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48275/1952

Comment: If the problem is that the publisher doesn't have `pgfplotstable` installed, they are using a very old distribution. In CTAN you can find some other [`csv` processing tools](http://ctan.org/topic/csv-support) which, may be, the publisher accepts.

Comment: I don't even know if they have the package, I'm just trying to follow guidelines that recommend using the basic `table` environment. You've convinced me that I should just try submitting without overthinking this. :)

Comment: May be it's better that you ask if this `guideline` implies that `pgfplotstable` is not a valid solution before submitting.

Comment: You are probably right. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgfplotstable` generates a `tabular` environment, that is then processed by LaTeX. By specifying an `outfile` this is exported to a file, which can then be imported into the original document (using `\input{filename}`) or directly copied into the original table environment.

See [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125097/126228) or search for `outfile` in the `pgfplotstable` manual.

Comment: Apparently `pgfplotstable` is very standard so I probably won't need this but this is exactly what I was asking for, so thanks.